# WPF: I cannot reuse a window (custom massagebox) after it has been closed

Tags: c#, wpf

I needed to create a custom "message box" for alert empty fields. When a field is empty (Like customer First Name, Last Name, Address, ...) my message box is loaded.
But it only happens one time and other time I give the following error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMEGx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzN2i.png)

---

winMessageAlert.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using DataModelLayer;
using SaleAndStorageSystems.Module;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Media;



namespace SaleAndStorageSystems.Windows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for winUsers.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class winMessageAlert : Window
    {
        public winMessageAlert()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string varTitle = "";
        public string varMessage = "";

        private void winMessageAlert1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();

            lblTitle.Content = varTitle;
            txtMessage.Text = varMessage;
        }
        private void recHeader_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }
    }
}
```

---

winAddEditCustomer.xaml.cs

```
 winMessageInformation MywinMessageInformation = new winMessageInformation();
        winMessageAlert MywinMessageAlert = new winMessageAlert();

        SaleAndStorageSystemsEntities MyDatabase = new SaleAndStorageSystemsEntities();

        private bool CheckNullable()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MywinMessageAlert.varTitle = "بدون مقدار";
                MywinMessageAlert.varMessage = "نام مشتری خالی می باشد";
                MywinMessageAlert.UpdateLayout();
                MywinMessageAlert.ShowDialog();

                txtFirstName.Focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MywinMessageAlert.varTitle = "بدون مقدار";
                MywinMessageAlert.varMessage = "نام خانوادگی مشتری خالی می باشد";
                MywinMessageAlert.ShowDialog();

                txtLastName.Focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCellPhone.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MywinMessageAlert.varTitle = "بدون مقدار";
                MywinMessageAlert.varMessage = "تلفن مشتری خالی می باشد";
                MywinMessageAlert.ShowDialog();

                txtCellPhone.Focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MywinMessageAlert.varTitle = "بدون مقدار";
                MywinMessageAlert.varMessage = "آدرس مشتری خالی می باشد";
                MywinMessageAlert.ShowDialog();

                txtAddress.Focus();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Code is made of text. Post your code as text not as links to images.

Comment: These kind of questions don't get a good response here in SO. You have to search before posting, know exactly what you need and post code of what you have tried so far. Not a bad question though. Also you need to learn naming conventions in C#. we have honor in them! Upvote and mark answer as accepted if you find it so. Comment if you need more help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

The error is completely clear in itself. When a form is closed by user or by calling `Close()` on it, it sort of disposes in the background (The hWnd gets destroyed to be exact but it doesn't matter) so you can't use it anymore.

To use a page multiple time you need to create an instance of it every time you want to show it like this:

```
MywinMessageAllert = new winMessageAlert();
```

and then the rest of your code.

Movafagh Baashid :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH "DEAR EMAD"

Damet Garm Dadash :-*